# how to use shellescape for a path with spaces in it

Tags: ruby

essentially, I have code like this (running on CentOS 6.5, ruby 2.3):

```
foo = "/opt/provisioning/workspace/jobs/This Has Spaces/files/thisfile.xml"
read_file_and_do_something_interesting(foo)
```

where we have:

```
def read_file_and_do_something_interesting(file_path)
  data = File.read(file_path)
```

which leads to error:

```
/opt/provision/jobs/lib/aws_tools.rb:498:in `read': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /opt/provisioning/workspace/jobs/This Has Spaces/files/thisfile.xml (Errno::ENOENT)
```

So, I tried to use shellescape, like this:

```
read_file_and_do_something_interesting(foo.shellescape)
```

and still I get error:

```
/opt/provision/jobs/lib/aws_tools.rb:498:in `read': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /opt/provisioning/workspace/jobs/This\ Has\ Spaces/files/thisfile.xml (Errno::ENOENT)
```

So, simply, how do you use this thing?

Comment: `File.read` shouldn't care about spaces in the filename as no shell is involved. Are you sure that you have the right filename?

Comment: `shellescape` is only necessary (and mandatory) when you're issuing shell commands, but that's not the case here. Make sure that actually exists. For example, `File.exist?("/opt/provisioning/workspace/jobs/This Has Spaces")` and so on.

Answer (score 2):

I think this file `/opt/provisioning/workspace/jobs/This Has Spaces/files/thisfile.xml` really not exists.

Can you run `ls "/opt/provisioning/workspace/jobs/This Has Spaces/files/thisfile.xml"`?